# Alternative to Pocket (online bookmark storing)

Tags: gratis, android, open-source, firefox, bookmark

Now that Firefox has "integrated" [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/), it lost most of its useful features (especially the drop-down list of saved articles, the indicator that a page was already bookmarked, the edit feature). With the original addon no longer available, that makes me looking for an alternative. Here's what I need:

- integration with Firefox

  - one-click bookmarking, ideally from within the location bar (2-click acceptable :)
  - indicator in the location bar whenever a page "bookmarked" with this service is shown
  - captures title and URL in the bookmark
  - drop-down list with stored bookmarks
  - the "reader-friendly page" for each article is not needed (I use it only to "exchange URLs between devices")
- integration with Android

  - integrates with the "Share Menu", so I can add to it from any app (e.g. RSS Reader, Twitter, Browser, …)
  - no reader/download for offline use needed. Access to the bookmark list would be a nice-to-have, but also not strictly required.
  - must be browser independent (no, I don't use Firefox on Android)
- general

  - self-hosted is fine (indeed even preferred)
  - free and open-source strongly preferred
  - integration with ownCloud would be fantastic

Comment: Note: [OhMyPocket](https://github.com/zhy0216/random-read) is written with the same background. As of now, there's only a Chrome extension available unfortunately. And it seems to use its own backend; so it's not as simple as just to load that as Firefox addon and keep the rest working (different storage). // *Wallabag* sounds promising as well, but I couldn't figure out if it matches my requirements (too much effort to install it just to see if it does). Of course, I'm open for other alternatives as well :)

Comment: Note: *Wallabag* seems to at least [plan to go this direction](https://github.com/wallabag/firefox-ext/issues/19), and might one day fit :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the best alternative to Pocket (formerly "Read it Later") is [**Wallabag**](https://www.wallabag.org/).

Features:

- runs on your own server
- completely free as in free beer
- cleans your webpages and stores them in a local database
- you can import all your Pocket articles with a couple of clicks, and it re-downloads them add adds them to the local database
- one-click bookmarking works with Chrome (don't know about Firefox)
- is actively developed

For your needs you can create a feature request right here:
https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag/issues

Disclaimer: I'm a iOS and Android developer working with the Wallabag guys, so I might start working on your feature request once you raise it :-)

Comment: Thanks, daredevil! Could you please outline in your answer how Wallabag currently matches the requirements listed in my question? I'm of course aware of Wallabag, but the last time I've checked there were a couple of things missing.

Comment: "completely free as in free beer": Maybe this is new since 2016, but Wallabag is now also free as in "free speech" and "freedom". That is, it's an open source project. Nice!